# Нецелое число массива

Tags: php

Число массива передается в value формы, но нужно передавать нецелое число. Как это сделать? К примеру 1.82

```
<?php
$city = array (
  'Местные розы' => array (
    'quantity' => array (
      11 => '11 шт. (минимум)',
      25 => '25 шт.',
      51 => '51 шт.',
      101 => '101 шт.',
    ),
    'lengths' => array (
      60 => '60 см',
      70 => '70 см',
    ),
  ),
  'Эквадорские розы' => array (
    'quantity' => array (
      25 => '25 шт. (минимум)',
      51 => '51 шт.',
      76 => '76 шт.',
      101 => '101 шт.',
    ),
    'lengths' => array (
      1.82 => '50 см',
      60 => '50 см',
      70 => '70 см',
    ),
  ),
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ключ массива может быть только целым (`integer`) или строкой (`string`)](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php).
Поэтому преобразуйте `float` в строку и будет Вам рабочий ключ.

Comment: Как это сделать?)

Comment: @bakusite, `(string) $yourFloatKey`.